# How to get all outputs in "Release" subfolder with CMake?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

My `CMakeLists.txt` file for windows is the following.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(LogMsg)

# Set the project source files
set(SOURCES
    LogMsg.cpp
    LogMsgMain.rc
    LogMsg.h
    resource.h
    stdafx.h
)

# Add executable target
add_library(LogMsg SHARED ${SOURCES})

# Set the configuration-specific outputs
set_target_properties(LogMsg PROPERTIES
    RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Debug"
    RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Release"
)

# Add include directories
target_include_directories(LogMsg PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

# Specify custom build commands
add_custom_command(TARGET LogMsg POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/LogMsg.rc" "$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:LogMsg>"
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/LogMsg.h" "$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:LogMsg>"
)
```

I run:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -S . -B .
cmake --build . --config Release
```

Within the `Release` subfolder I am getting **.dll** file, **.rc** and **.h** file.

However, directory `LogMsg.tlog` and some other files such as: `LogMsg.dll.recipe`, `LogMsg.obj` and `LogMsgMain.res` are generated within the path `LogMsg.dir/Release` and I cannot find how is this defined since I would like it in the `Release` folder immediately.

Comment: CMake allows to redefine output directory only for certain build artefacts. Other build artefacts are generated in the build directory under specific subdirectories and there is no way to change that. Why do you want to produce `.obj` in your own directory? Why do you ever want to output binaries into source directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short answer:

you can use the following commands:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -S . -B ./Release
cmake --build ./Release --config Release
```

## Long answer:

When you want to generate a project build-system, you can use the following command:

```
cmake [<options>] -S <path-to-source> -B <path-to-build>
```

In your command, the **path-to-build** is "`.`", this means that the **target build location(path-to-build)** is current location, so some files are generated in the current location. If you want to get all outputs in the **`Release`** folder, just use this command:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -S . -B ./Release
```

the output files will be generated in your target location(**`./Release`**).

When you want to build a project, you can use the following command:

```
cmake --build <dir> [<options>] [-- <build-tool-options>]
```

for your project, use this command:

```
cmake --build ./Release --config Release
```

the output files will be generated in your target location.

For more information, please refer to [CMake  Documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html).

Comment: Thank you!
Can you please assist me with the following question as well? Thanks a lot
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76338106/cmake-how-to-produce-both-dll-and-lib-as-ouputs

Comment: @vel I have added a comment under your new question.

Comment: please accept my apology - I have permuted the question - I am getting .lib but not getting .dll. please sorry